# Having trouble with mavik2pro drone in webots

Tags: python, webots

I was hoping someone could help me with my code. I am having trouble getting my drone to work, which is weird since the code worked before I had to restart the computer. But it keeps saying NameError: name 'mavic2Pro' is not defined. But I checked the names and cannot find the issue.

Error:
[image]

Mavik2Pro details:

[image]

Code:

```
from controller import Robot
from time import sleep

me = Mavic2Pro.Mavic2_Pro()
me.connect()

print(me.get_battery())
me.takeoff()
me.send_rc_control(0, 50, 0, 0)
sleep(2)
me.send_rc_control(0, 0, 0, 0)
me.land()
timestep = int(Mavic2Pro.getBasicTimeStep())
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to File and open sample projects, there you can find mavic 2 pro example.In that example observe how controller is written.